# SQL Server Geography Query works but Geometry Query Does Not - Different Tables, Similar Schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

I am trying to get a Geometry query to work. A similar Geography query works fine but I must work with a table that uses a Geometry type. Although the Geography version returns lots of records as expected, I cannot get the Geometry version to return any records. Both tables have exactly the same latitude and longitude records .

This Geography query works fine:

```
DECLARE @home GEOGRAPHY
SET @home = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(-0.7799193 51.3083162 )', 4326);

SELECT OutwardCode, InwardCode, Latitude, Longitude
FROM dbo.PostCodeData
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(@home) <= (5 * 1609) -- 1609 = approx metres in 1 mile
```

The table schema is:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|    Field    |     Type     |
+-------------+--------------+
| OutwardCode | Varchar(4)   |
| InwardCode  | Varchar(3)   |
| Latitude    | Decimal(9,6) |
| Longitude   | Decimal(9,6) |
| GeoLocation | Geography    |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Example Table Data:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| OutwardCode | InwardCode | Longitude  | Latitude |                  GeoLocation                   |
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| GU14        | 9HL        | -0.7803759 | 51.30818 | 0xE6100000010C01A4367172A7494027C522E1D6F8E8BF |
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

This Geometry query returns no records (I have exactly the same latitude and longitude records in the database but have Geometry as a centre point for the street and Postcode is a joined version of OutwardCode and InwardCode):

```
DECLARE @home GEOMETRY
SET @home = GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(51.3083162 -0.7799193)', 0);

SELECT Postcode, Latitude, Longitude
FROM dbo.OS_Locator
WHERE Centre.STDistance(@home) <= (5 * 1609) -- 1609 = approx metres in 1 mile
```

The table schema is:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|   Field   |     Type     |
+-----------+--------------+
| Postcode  | nvarchar(10) |
| Latitude  | Decimal(9,6) |
| Longitude | Decimal(9,6) |
| Centre    | Geometry     |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Example Table Data:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
| Postcode | Latitude  | Longitude |                     Centre                     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
| GU14 9HL | 51.308304 | -0.779928 | 0x346C0000010C00000000549C1D410000000018330341 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason that there are two distinct geospatial types. Geography is for when your coordinates represent degrees of latitude and longitude for points on Earth (a three-dimensional object with singularities in its coordinate system). Geometry is for when your points represent arbitrary X & Y positions on an infinite plane. You can't just say "I'll take 51.3 degrees and make it the X coordinate" and have everything just work out. As my high school physics teacher always said "units are important".

Comment: OK. I'm new to this but understand more each time with solid explanations like this. I had used a bulk import SQL Script I found on the web to get my Ordinance Survey data into SQL Server. I see the script did the conversion to GEOMETRY. I ended up creating a new GEOGRAPHY type and running another script to convert the latitude and longitude to that GEOGRAPHY type accordingly. All works fine now.